# if a function can be created based on different input information?

Tags: python, function, functional-programming

I have the following question, I am wondering if there is a solution or not.

Because I just learned the function can be a variable in python, I am wondering if it is possible to design a function which create different function based on the input.

let's say, we have a long list of chars:
`longlist = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Given the an test list, `test = [1,2,3]`

An function (func1) can read the **test list as input** and return **a function (func2) as output**.
This function can be used to separate the long list of chars into different group and print out 
`a,bc,def,g,hi,jkl,o,pq....` which follow the test list 1,2,3 pattern and repeat again.

if the test list is `test = [1,2,3,4]`

`then func1(test) --> func2
 func2(longlist) prints out a,bc,def,ghij,k,lm,n`

In this case, it follows the 1,2,3,4,1,2... pattern

The example I made looks not so interesting, but the fundamental question is if the function can be created based on different input information?

Comment: You might be looking for "function currying"

Comment: Look at `functools.partial` for a good example.

Comment: Decorators that "take arguments" are doing exactly this. It's actually a factory that returns a custom decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is called a closure. The inner function (`func2`) keeps the scope that it was defined in. Try this:

```
def func1(x):
    def func2(y):
        ret = []
        for f in x * len(y):
            ret += [y[:f]]
            y = y[f:]
            if not y: 
                return ret
    return func2

print(func1([1, 2, 3, 4])('This should do what you want'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function within the first function and return it later. Function 1 can be used to set up params, etc. Below is an implementation of your particular question.

```
def make_func(params):
# Params must be a list of integers
    def split_string_in_pattern(string):
        res = []
        pattern_index = 0
        while True:
            res.append(string[:params[pattern_index]])
            print(res)
            string = string[params[pattern_index]:]
            print(string)
            if not string:
                return res
            if pattern_index >= len(params) - 1:
                pattern_index = 0
            else:
                pattern_index += 1
    return split_string_in_pattern

""" Test """ 
long_string = 'asdqweasdasdacasdasdadas'
split_func = make_func([1,2,3,4])
split_func(long_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations

# Here you can use which one is more suited for your situation: permutations or combinations

def func1(test):
    def func2(longlist):
        result = []
        for t in test:
            perms = permutations(longlist, t)
            result += perms
        result = [''.join(t) for t in result]
        return result
    return func2

f2 = func1([1, 2])
print(f2('abc'))
```

You get

['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb'] if you used permutations

['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc'] if you used combinations